# Mouseover one feature to highlight another feature leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have created a map using leaflet that displays information about states upon mouseover and on click it goes to another page. Recently, I have needed to place labels on the map as well. Since, I am using GeoJSON features, there is no easy way to add the labels with a plugin. I have used a base map to put labels on the map and for small states I have used a line out to the label that is hovering over empty space. I am trying to tie a rectangle feature that encases the label to the state feature in order to make the state highlight. I have tried putting the coordinates in the same feature in the geojson but that causes the label feature to be color and we want the label feature to remain hidden.

Here is the map section of my code:

```
var map = L.map('map', {zoomControl: false}).setView([38.165, -98.613], 4);

/*L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/wcgislab.k1dm05p3/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    id: 'wcgislab.k1dm05p3'
}).addTo(map);*/

var states = <?php echo json_encode($features);?>;

var imageUrl = 'http://www.link.com/images/map.jpg',
    imageBounds = [[52.5, -128], [20, -129], [20, -52], [53, -51.5]];

L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);

function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;
    var feature = e.target.feature;
    if(feature.properties.STATE_TYPE == "Label")
        {

        }
        else
        {
            layer.setStyle({
                weight: 5,
                color: '#666',
                dashArray: '',
                fillOpacity: 0.9
            });

            if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
                layer.bringToFront();
            }
        }
        info.update(layer.feature.properties);
    }

    function gotofeature(e) {
        var feature = e.target.feature;

        window.location.href = 'http://www.link.com/state.php?State='+feature.properties.State_Abbr;

    }

    function getColor(str){
        switch (str) {
            case 'A': return "#00cc58";
            case 'A+': return "#00cc58";
            case 'A-': return "#00cc58";
            case 'B': return "#a3e300";
            case 'B+': return "#a3e300";
            case 'B-': return "#a3e300";
            case 'C': return "#faa200";
            case 'C+': return "#f2fa00";
            case 'C-': return "#f2fa00";
            case 'D-F': return "#fa2e00";
        }
    }

    function resetHighlight(e) {
        geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
        info.update();
    }

    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            click: gotofeature
        });
    }

    geojson = L.geoJson(states, {
        style: function(feature) {
            if(feature.properties.STATE_TYPE != "Label")
            {
                switch (feature.properties.data.<?php echo $grade;?>) {
                    case 'A': return {fillColor: "#00cc58", fillOpacity: .72, weight: 2, opacity: 1, color: 'white', dashArray: '3'};
                    case 'A+': return {fillColor: "#00cc58", fillOpacity: .72, weight: 2, opacity: 1, color: 'white', dashArray: '3'};
                    case 'A-': return {fillColor: "#00cc58", fillOpacity: .72, weight: 2, opacity: 1, color: 'white', dashArray: '3'};
                    case 'B': return {fillColor: "#a3e300", fillOpacity: .72, weight: 2, opacity: 1, color: 'white', dashArray: '3'};
                    case 'B+': return {fillColor: "#a3e300", fillOpacity: .72, weight: 2, opacity: 1, color: 'white', dashArray: '3'};
                    case 'B-': return {fillColor: "#a3e300", fillOpacity: .72, weight: 2, opacity: 1, color: 'white', dashArray: '3'};
                    case 'C': return {fillColor: "#faa200", fillOpacity: .72, weight: 2, opacity: 1, color: 'white', dashArray: '3'};
                    case 'C+': return {fillColor: "#faa200", fillOpacity: .72, weight: 2, opacity: 1, color: 'white', dashArray: '3'};
                    case 'C-': return {fillColor: "#faa200", fillOpacity: .72, weight: 2, opacity: 1, color: 'white', dashArray: '3'};
                    case 'D': return {fillColor: "#fa2e00", fillOpacity: .72, weight: 2, opacity: 1, color: 'white', dashArray: '3'};
                    case 'D+': return {fillColor: "#fa2e00", fillOpacity: .72, weight: 2, opacity: 1, color: 'white', dashArray: '3'};
                    case 'D-': return {fillColor: "#fa2e00", fillOpacity: .72, weight: 2, opacity: 1, color: 'white', dashArray: '3'};
                    case 'F': return {fillColor: "#fa2e00", fillOpacity: .72, weight: 2, opacity: 1, color: 'white', dashArray: '3'};
                    case 'F+': return {fillColor: "#fa2e00", fillOpacity: .72, weight: 2, opacity: 1, color: 'white', dashArray: '3'};
                    case 'F-': return {fillColor: "#fa2e00", fillOpacity: .72, weight: 2, opacity: 1, color: 'white', dashArray: '3'};
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return {fillcolor: 'white', fillOpacity: 0, weight: 0, opacity: 0, color: 'white', dashArray: '3'};
            }
        },
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(map);

    var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

    legend.onAdd = function (map) {

        var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
            grades = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D-F'],
            labels = ['<i style="background:#00cc58"></i>'];

        // loop through our density intervals and generate a label with a colored square for each interval
        for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            div.innerHTML +=
                '<div class="info_labels"><i style="background:' + getColor(grades[i])+ '"></i> ' +
                grades[i] + '</div>';
        }

        return div;
    };


    var info = L.control();

    info.onAdd = function (map) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
        this.update();
        return this._div;
    };

    // method that we will use to update the control based on feature properties passed
    info.update = function (props) {
        this._div.innerHTML = '<h4><?php echo $title;?><br>' + (props ?
            "<span>" + props.STATE_NAME + "</span><br><span style='font-size:16px'>" +props.data.<?php echo $subject."Score_Grade";?> +'</span>' 
            : 'Hover over a state');
    };

    info.addTo(map);

    function numberWithCommas(x) {
        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }

    map.dragging.disable();
    map.touchZoom.disable();
    map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
    map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();

    legend.addTo(map);
```

Comment: I am also waiting for the answer